# How can I get the Hit point on hit test between two dynamically added objects in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, hittest

I want to know the actual hit point when the dash line is hitting to the triangle object.

I am using the following codes for hit between two object :

```
target.hitTestObject(border);
```

where **target** is the triangle object and **border** is a group where I placed a rectangle with stroke SolidColorDash.

And I am using the following codes for getting the hit coordinate :

```
var x:Number = target.x;
var y:Number = target.y;
```

And it is giving the x and y coordinate when the dash line is touching to the boundary of the triangle object but I want the coordinate when dash line will touch the bitmapdata of the triangle object.

[image]

So Anybody have an idea how to resolve this issue or how to get the hit coordinate.

Comment: Check for pixel-perfect collision libraries, some of them night have this implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HitTest not working correctly when using Graphics.lineTo/curveTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923615/hittest-not-working-correctly-when-using-graphics-lineto-curveto)

Comment: Thanks @Vesper pixel-perfect collision solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**The Following Codes Solve my Problem for getting real collision:**

```
private var returnValue:Boolean;
private var firstPoint:Point;
private var secondPoint:Point;
private var firstRectangle:Rectangle;
private var secondRectangle:Rectangle;
private var firstObjectBmpData:BitmapData;
private var secondObjectBmpData:BitmapData;
private var firstOffSetMatrix:Matrix;
private var secondOffSetMatrix:Matrix;

public function testCollision(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
{
        returnValue = false;

        firstRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
        secondRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);

        if(secondRectangle.width != 0 && secondRectangle.height != 0 && firstRectangle.width != 0 && firstRectangle.height != 0)
        {
            firstObjectBmpData = new BitmapData(firstRectangle.width, firstRectangle.height, true, 0);
            firstObjectBmpData.draw(clip1);

            secondObjectBmpData = new BitmapData(secondRectangle.width, secondRectangle.height, true, 0);
            secondObjectBmpData.draw(clip2);

            firstPoint = new Point(clip1.x, clip1.y)
            secondPoint =  new Point(clip2.x, clip2.y)

            if (firstObjectBmpData.hitTest(firstPoint, 255, secondObjectBmpData, secondPoint, 255))
            {
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
}
```